# How do I import an ASCII grid using arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python-2.7, arcpy, esri-ascii-raster

I'm trying to automate the setup of some flood depth/hazard maps. The user specifies a folder containing depth grids generated by a hydraulic model (.asc format) and some background mapping (geotiff format). I've got the mapping to import correctly using code similar to that below. But the code does not work for the ASCII datasets.

```
depthgrid = "<userspecifiedfolder>\\maximumdepthgrid.asc"
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, depthgrid)
```

Upon running the code I get the error: "AssertionError"

Conversion from ASCII to another filetype is not really an option as I need the files in this ASCII format for various other tasks too and would prefer not to double up on data.

Example ASCII data:

ncols     2068

nrows     1522

xllcorner       516810.000

yllcorner       466168.000

cellsize        1.000

NODATA_value      -999.

-999.0000 -999.0000 -999.0000 -999.0000 -999.0000 -999.0000 ...

more data ...

Comment: Can you view the ASCII files in Catalog? Frequently files called ASCII are not the format that Esri anticipates hence the error. http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm

Comment: Is it possible to shorten asc file name

Comment: I'd really like to see the first dozen lines. ASCII files are supported by Esri as an image format however software like CAD packages have been known to export gridded X,Y,Z with the .asc extension; other text-based image formats exist as an interchange that could be considered ASCII as that's simply the character set the text is presented in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII , so all it's saying is the file is 'text'. Only the Esri ASCII (on previous comments' link) is the correct format to load as an image.

Comment: I am able to see the data in ArcCatalog. I'm also able to add the data to ArcMap manually using the black/yellow Add Data button. I've added some example data to the original question above. Ta.

Comment: AddLayer is only supposed to work with .lyr files or with layers already in the TOC of an mxd. How do you even manage to import the Geotiffs using this function?

Comment: Thanks GISGe - I've got a feeling it might be because the tiffs were already in the mxd from an earlier tool I was running, hence why they can be re-added using AddLayer. In that case I need to know how to import geotiffs too!

Comment: FYI @GISGe - I've just tried my code out on a fresh mxd and it brings the geotiffs in correctly! So it's still just the ASCIIs that I'm having trouble with. I think your idea of having the dummy ASCII layer in our template that we can use to copy and replace data sources is probably the best bet for now. Thanks everyone for the tips / help!

Comment: Yes adding a layer to an mxd as a result of a geoprocessing operation is another trick, especially in your case, as the GP step seems to be part of your workflow anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have .lyr files or an existing mxd referencing the data, I think what you're trying to do should be impossible with Python.

A better approach would be to create (manually) a template mxd with a geotiff and an ascii file in it, then (with Python): copy the template mxd (with [saveACopy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/MapDocument/00s30000000n000000/)) and replace the data sources of both layers with e.g. [replaceDataSource](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/).